# Make textobject bold based on condition in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

In my crystal report, there are two columns `Name` and `Amount`. What i want is if `Amount` is blank then `Name` must be bold otherwise it will be in regular font. I don't know how to write formula for this condition. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to:

- Right-click the "Name" field
- Select "Format Object"
- Click the formula button next to "Style"

If your *Amount* field is a number (probably is, but you used the phrase "is blank"), then compare it to 0 instead of an empty string.

[image]

Comment: Formula cant be save and gives error `The formula result must be a string`

Comment: here, you need to check two condition first is IsNull({FieldName})=False and second is {FieldName}=0 instead of ="". or you can try to convert that field using ToText but it will returns 0 as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if Isnull(<<Databsefield Amount>>)
then crBold
Else crRegular
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ({DatabaseField.Column1}="Your Text") then
    crBold
else if({DatabaseField.Column1}="Your Text") then
    crBold
else
    crRegular
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).