# How to add a line object above the last row of crystal report data source's data table and how to make the last row's font style bold?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've created a datatable `dtAllStudentMarksDetail` in `C#` which has 5 columns

```
Student Name |  Maths Marks | Physics Marks | Chemistry Marks  | Total Marks
```

and added a row at the last of the table which have total no of students in student name's column, total aggregate marks of Maths in Math marks' column and so on. Now i have set the crystal report's datasource dtAllStudentMarksDetail table. Now i want to make that last row which contains the total numbers font in bold and also want to add a line object above that row.

Is this possible using any sort of formula or i have to remove the last row from datatable and add an extra in the footer section and use formula fields to show the last field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total summary of all student's entry, you did not add row in data-table, right, because crystal report have facility to give summary of your records.

Here you need to some step.

1. Remove summary row from your datatable.
2. In design mode of crystal report, set fields in detail section.
3. To get summary, add summary fields in report footer section or
   group footer section. The footer section is used to show summarize view of your detail section, no need to do any thing for summary.

Check this link - http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-summary-field.htm

Second approach is add formula with sum of field(s), and set in footer, http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=680307

**Updated**
Based on your comment, this is you need. you can bold it via simple property of each field and also in property popup you can bold based on your condition like if field value(Student's Marks) is 80% then bold.

[Make textobject bold based on condition in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607927/make-textobject-bold-based-on-condition-in-crystal-report)

Comment: This is helpful but if there is anyway by which i can identify the last row in crystal report or identify rows in crystal report then that would be great because i'm also thinking about make the rows bold of those students who got above **80%** in Total Marks. So i'm asking that is there any way i can identify rows in crystal report?